# How simultaneous downloads with FTP works?

Tags: java, ftp

When you look at software like FileZilla, it can handle multiples file transfers simultaneously.

I'm implementing in Java an FTP Client, but I don't know how to handle simultaneous transfers.

1) Does the FTP protocol allow receiving multiples files simultaneously with an unique "command-connection" and multiples "data-connection" (PASV) ?

OR

2) Does the FTP protocol require for each transfer one "command-connection" AND one "data-connection" (PASV) ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that clients like FileZilla use multiple connections to the server(s). First, they consider the file in segments. Then they interleave worker threads for those file segments (probably from a pool) with connections (and may connect to multiple mirrors simultaneously) in an attempt to maximize download speed.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you think that for each file to be transferred simultaneously, it is required to have 2 connections (data+and command, so resend each time user and pass) ? or just 1 connection for commands and multiples connections for files-tranfer ? Thanks!

Comment: @user3453330 Yes. Passive vs Active is just which side opens the second connection. Read [this](http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html) if you're still confused.

Comment: Usually you can only have a single data transfer within an ftp login, so you need to login again for each transfer.